# Web Audio APIs - Capture audio - Disable low pass filter

Tags: javascript, audio, web

I use this tutorial: http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/

and this live demo page: http://typedarray.org/wp-content/projects/WebAudioRecorder/

to create my high frequency analyzer.

My problem is that Web Audio API, i thing, by default cut off high frequencies.

When i record WAV and play 10000hz signal, wav contain my freq.

If i play 17000hz signal, wav don't contain my freq.

How to disable low pass filter?

code:

```
function success(e){
    // creates the audio context
    audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new audioContext();

    // creates a gain node
    volume = context.createGain();

    // creates an audio node from the microphone incoming stream
    audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(e);

    // connect the stream to the gain node
    audioInput.connect(volume);

    /* From the spec: This value controls how frequently the audioprocess event is 
    dispatched and how many sample-frames need to be processed each call. 
    Lower values for buffer size will result in a lower (better) latency. 
    Higher values will be necessary to avoid audio breakup and glitches */
    var bufferSize = 2048;
    recorder = context.createJavaScriptNode(bufferSize, 2, 2);

    recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){
        console.log ('recording');
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData (0);
        var right = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData (1);
        // we clone the samples
        leftchannel.push (new Float32Array (left));
        rightchannel.push (new Float32Array (right));
        recordingLength += bufferSize;
    }

    // we connect the recorder
    volume.connect (recorder);
    recorder.connect (context.destination); 
}
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant coed.

Comment: you can see code now

Answer (score 1):

This is in `getUserMedia` and not the Web Audio API. By default, the `MediaStream` that `getUserMedia` gives you contains data that has been (depending on the browser):
- echo cancelled
- had the noise suppressed
- had automatic gain compensation applied

You can disable those using constraints (for example, for Firefox):

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: { 
   echoCancellation: false,
   mozNoiseSuppression: false,
   mozAutoGainControl: false
});`

We are currently standardizing those properties, but we're not done yet.

Comment: Yes this does in fact work for desktop Firefox. I am hoping it works for mobile firefox as well. Desktop chrome seems to default to these filters OFF/False for getUserMedia() but mobile Chrome and mobile Firefox does not. I am hoping this also works for mobile Firefox at least. Any ideas on how to turn OFF all filters for mobile Chrome and mobile Safari (which has just allowed getUserMedia with iOS11)?

Comment: Still an issue in 2019 for iOS Safari and most Android mobile devices, any solutions yet?