# Audio recorded with Web Audio API is truncated at the beginning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I am working on a piece of software in which I need to record the user voice for a later use in voice recognition. Surprisingly it's the audio recording part I'm having difficulties with, for now.

In the procedure, the user has to speak words written on the screen and I record each word they speak individually. The problem I have is that some recording are truncated at the beginning or at the end, leaving with only a part of the word.
The recording do start before the user speaks, so it leaves me with recordings of ~1s of silence, then the truncated user speech. So the problem is not that I start recording too late.

Here is my simple code for requesting access to the microphone:

```js
navigator.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: false,
    noiseSuppression: false,
    autoGainControl: false
  }
}, this._handleUserMedia.bind(this), () => {
  this.setState({
    recorderAvailable: false
  });
});

_handleUserMedia(stream) {
  this._mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  this._mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
    this._mediaBuffer.push(event.data);
  };

  this._mediaRecorder.onstart = () => {
    console.log("Recording started");
    document.getElementById("wordsStage").style.color = "red";
  }

  this._mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
    // Create an URL to download the recording
    this.state.results[this.state.currentWordIdx].recordingUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(this._mediaBuffer));

    // Reinitialize the buffer for next recording
    this._mediaBuffer = [];
    console.log("Recording stopped");
    document.getElementById("wordsStage").style.color = "black";

    this._gotoNextWord();
  };

  this._gotoNextWord();
}
```

And here is my code that starts / stops the recording:

```js
_registerAnswer(isCorrect) {
  this.state.results.push({
    word: this.props.data.words[this._currentWordIdx],
    isCorrect
  });

  this._mediaRecorder && this._mediaRecorder.state === "recording" && this._mediaRecorder.stop();

  // mediaRecorder.onstop handler will trigger the next word once the recording has been saved
}

_gotoNextWord() {
  const dataSource = this.state.isDoingExamples ? this.props.data.examples : this.props.data.words;
  if (this._currentWordIdx < dataSource.length - 1) {
    // Starts the recording
    !this.state.isDoingExamples && this._mediaRecorder && this._mediaRecorder.start(500);

    // displays the concentration point
    this._displayWordOnStage(null, true);

    // displays the current word after the concentration's point duration elapsed
    setTimeout(() => this._displayWordOnStage(++this._currentWordIdx), Shared.FocusPointDurationInMs);
  } else if (this.state.isDoingExamples) {
    this._currentWordIdx = -1;
    this.setState({
        isDoingExamples: false
      },
      this._gotoNextWord
    );
  } else {
    this._finishTraining();
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm in the context of a React component. Also, I tried setting the default audio processing to false (I discovered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506794/web-audio-apis-capture-audio-disable-low-pass-filter)) because I thought those processings may wrongly affect my audio, but no success.

**EDIT:** I'm starting to think it's because of React in the context of Electron, that would add some overhead that would negatively impact the recording. I tested a recorder in simple HTML/CSS/JS, then only in Electron, then only with React, and the three have no problem. Does that make sense?

**EDIT 2**: The author of [this blog post](https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/) says that in Chrome, the `noiseSuppression` constraint is not supported although it is on, so I can't turn it off. Newer versions of Chrome do have the constraint but the version embedded in Electron doesn't have it: it is not listed when using `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints();`. It seams that this would be the reason why most words are truncated at the beginning right?
Well I tried within Electron but not using React and it's OK, so it cannot be that...

**EDIT 3**: I updated Electron to the latest version (2.0.3) that includes Chrome 61.0.3163.100. I still have the problem.

Comment: Not related but the Navigator.getUserMedia API is deprecated. Please switch to the up to date *MediaDevices.getUserMedia*. As to the truncation problem, hard to really know... By experience, short recordings may indeed have some issue... But your MediaRecorder part seems correct, so if the err is on your side, that would be in the `start()` and `stop()` logic, that you carefully omitted in your question ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I added more code :-)